# Find matching words

Tags: grep

I have a corpus file and the rules file. I am trying to find matching words where the word from rule appear in corpus.

```
# cat corpus.txt
this is a paragraph number one
second line
third line

# cat rule.txt
a
b
c
```

This returns 2 lines

```
# grep -F0 -f rule.txt corpus.txt
this is a paragraph number one
second line
```

But I am expecting 4 words like this...

```
a
paragraph
number
second
```

Trying to achive these results using grep or awk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming words are seperated by white spaces

`awk '{print "\\S*" $1 "\\S*"}' rule.txt | grep -m 4 -o -f - corpus.txt`

Comment: This returns all the words and not just 4 expected words.

Comment: You can use `-m NUM` to limit matches.